# Debug QgsDataSourceUri as a QgsVectorLayer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, I don't know how to debug it when it doesn't work.

Basically I'm working with this code:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(str(host), str(port), str(dbname), str(username), str(password))
uri.setDataSource(str(schema), str(table), str(geom_col), '', 'field_row_id')
uri.setKeyColumn('field_row_id')
uri.setSrid('4326')
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), str(extra_name) + str(table), 'postgres')
print(uri.uri())
```

Prints something like this: `'dbname=\'hortegarden\' host=geodatafarm.com port=5432 user=\'my_username\' password=\'my_password\' key=\'field_row_id\' srid=4326 table="harvest"."dyback_2015" (pos) sql='`

`field_row_id` is a valid primary key with unique values.
I can add the table from the source manager, hence I want it to be apart of my plugin. Though the source from the working layer properties looks like this: 
`dbname='hortegarden' host=geodatafarm.com port=5432 sslmode=disable authcfg=0xq253x key='field_row_id' srid=4326 type=Point table="harvest"."dyback_2015" (pos) sql=`

Any suggestion how I can investigate why it is not valid?

Comment: Maybe try  to add the table from the source manager, copy the source string in the general tab of the layer property and past it instead of 'uri.uri()' ? What happens? Is this source string  different from the 'uri.uri()' ?

Comment: I added the connection info from the property of the working layer and the output from uri.uri()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, the problem was an unstable wifi connection :(